# What is a "biscuit"?

Tags: beer, flavor, malt

When reading about malt and beer flavors, I often come across words like "biscuity" and "biscuitlike".

Where I live (Western Canada) "biscuit" is a somewhat ambiguous term, and is not used much.  When I hear the word I would generally think of either (1) a scone-like bun that we used to get with our Kentucky Fried Chicken when I was young, or (2) some generic sort of cookie.

Can anyone enlighten me as to what "biscuit" means in the context of beer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Good Eats - Biscuits](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3QuQSdjMVE)

I'm a good ol' boy, though, so ours are like scones without sugar in them.   In beer, it's pretty much malt flavors and aromas that mimic the flavor and aroma of biscuits.   Lightly toasted bread.

Comment: Gahhhhhh as another good ol' boy, I'll say there's not much else that equals the aroma of fresh biscuits. If I could have a pale ale that smells like like biscuits + hops + alcohol, I'd probably drown in it.

Answer (score 3):

It's between those two things, but closer to the bun.  Dry, very slightly sweet, more lightly-caramel-y, toasty, grainy.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a "biscuit malt", typically either English or Belgian in origin, which is a lightly roasted malt. It gives a characteristic malty flavour to beers. It is great for "ordinary" ales, but use in moderation!